# OS X: Output routing on external sound card

Tags: macos, audio, usb, headphones

I have an external sound card connected via USB to my iMac. I connected to this sound card headphones and speakers.

When I play music sound comes together from my headphones and speakers, but I'd like to choose which output is active.

In my audio settings I can only choose "USB Audio Codec" (which is the correct name of my sound card, an Uphoria UM2)

My hardware and software is iMac 2019, Monterey 12.4

Is there a way how can I manage preferences for sound out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So @Tetsujin gave me an answer in the comment that sound card should have  individual physical volume controls for headphones & speakers.

I also went to official website for support with my question, and I've got the next answer:

"Regretfully there is no way to separate these outs. The UM2 is a basic interface, and the outs are shared on one knob. there isn't a way to separate this from the device itself. The workaround would be to get a separate headphone amp and adjust that volume externally."

I think it’s settled

Answer (score 1):

If there aren't switches on the audio unit itself, I'm not sure there's anything that the Mac can do to control the output once it's 'gone' to the unit.

You could try the Audio MIDI Setup.app, and create an Aggregate or Multi-Output device configured for certain outputs of your device.

Comment: Yeah, this type of device isn't designed to present as 2 outputs at OS-level. https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcu6M.png The more expensive ones have individual physical volume controls for headphones & speakers. https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPB7D.png This changes again as you get out of budget range but then tends to be controlled by its own 'control room' app or from within a DAW.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried, but it always shows me 2 outputs as a one available

I also tried to use BlackHole, but result was the same. Maybe I did something wrong, so I decided to ask

It's sad if there is no software solution for it ☹️

Comment: If it doesn't present as two outputs there's nothing you can do about it, sorry.